# Configure Prettier to ignore line after pattern?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Is there a way to configure Prettier (in VS Code) to ignore lines after a certain pattern?

I sometimes need  a directive like `/**@ts-ignore */` followed by a long line. When Prettier does its job it adds new lines to the long line making the directive `/**@ts-ignore */` useless.

Would it be possible to change the prettier config to ignore lines after `/**@ts-ignore */`?

**EDIT**: I think I might not have been describing it enough: for example this is one of the problem lines:

```
  {/**@ts-ignore */}
        <IconButton ref={ref}
          as={props['as']}
          bla
          bli
          bla
        />
```

prettier does this to the line:

```
  {/**@ts-ignore */}
        <IconButton 
          ref={ref}
          as={props['as']}
          bla
          bli
          bla
        />
```

which does not work anymore (since ts-ignore only ignores the following line. How can I tell prettier to ignore cases like that?

I hope it makes it a little clearer.
Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: prettier cannot be really configured. It will force a specific style on you, disregarding readability.

Answer (score 1):

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript

Prettier documentation has a good page about ignoring code. For javascript the comment is `// prettier-ignore`

Notice that using the comment will only ignore the next node in the AST.